# Why doesn't NSNull behave like nil for unimplemented methods?

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

As per my understanding, `NSNull` exists as a replacement of `nil` in situations where an object is explicitly required, such in `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` collections.

One of the good parts of `nil`'s behavior is that many verbose `null` checks can be skipped and it would convenient to have the same behavior implemented by `NSNull`. Consider the following example:

```
NSDictionary * json = // deserialized JSON from a REST service
NSString * name = json[@"first_name"];
if (name != nil && ![name isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [name isEqualToString:@"Gabriele"]) { ... }
```

the check can currently be simplified to

```
if (![name isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [name isEqualToString:@"Gabriele"]) { ... }
```

but if `[NSNull null`] was mimicking the behavior of `nil`, it could be simplified even more to

```
if ([name isEqualToString:@"Gabriele"]) { ... }
```

So my question is why didn't Apple override the `-forwardInvocation:` method of `NSObject` to mimic the behavior of `nil` on an unrecognized selectors?

I would like to get the philosophy behind it and to understand whether there is some drawback or some broken convention that I cannot think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that `nil`'s behavior is part of the Objective C language, not of any particular library. `NSNull`, on the other hand, is part of a library, with a single very specific purpose:

> The `NSNull` class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow `nil` values).

It is not intended for use as a "sentinel" object: if you wish to construct such an object, you can always do so, because collections themselves do not assign `NSNull` any particular significance. It is provided for programmers' convenience in situations when they wish to store `nil`s, so that programmers could avoid reinventing their own null object every time they need it.

Also note that `[NSNull null]` is a *singleton*, so you can compare it with `==` / `!=` operators instead of calling `isEqual:`

```
if (name != [NSNull null] && [name isEqualToString:@"Gabriele"])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure what do you mean for "sentinel". Anyway my point is that `NSNull` exists as a replacement for `nil`, so in my opinion it would be consistent for it to mimic its behavior.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella The class exists as a replacement for `nil` in very specific case of storing `nil` in a collection, not as a generic replacement for `nil` constant of the Objective C language. "Sentinel" is a kind of object that you may use to avoid performing a check, for `nil` or otherwise, letting you deal with objects in a uniform way. This is especially useful when your objects are inside a collection.

Comment: Thanks, I think the key relies on the difference levels of the implementations (language and framework). I'm still convinced that having `NSNull` to discard every message would be a sensible implementation, but I'm also starting to grasp the philosophy behind the current one.